# Convert XML Via PHP & Javascript Function

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I wonder whether someone could help me please.

I have an xml file which is made up of approx 22,000 OS Grid References, an extract is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
    - <Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    - <Row>
      <Name>Deserted medieval village</Name> 
      <NGR>SS 00000 11111</NGR> 
      </Row>
```

What I need to do for each 'NGR' is convert it to a Lat & Lng co-ordinate. If I were to do this manually I'd key the NGR onto a HTML form I have and use the following Javascript code (from nearby.org.uk) on a click event to convert it. I will then save it to a table in a mySQL database.

```
function converttolatlng() {
    var gr = document.getElementById('osgridref').value;

    var osgb = new GT_OSGB();


    if (osgb.parseGridRef(gr)) {
        var wgs84 = osgb.getWGS84();

        document.getElementById('osgb36lat').value = wgs84.latitude;
        document.getElementById('osgb36lon').value = wgs84.longitude;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('osgb36lat').value = "n/a";
        document.getElementById('osgb36lon').value = "n/a";
    }

}
```

Because I have so many, I'd like to be able to run this conversion automatically and from what I've read on the Internet I think the best way is to run the xml through PHP, but I must admit I'm not sure where to begin.

I just wondered if someone could perhaps take a look at this please and show me what I would need to do to create the extraction process.

Sincere thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an XML database, since your input document is XML? The code would then look like:

```
for $row in doc("input.xml")//Row
let $coordinates := parseGridRef($row/NGR)
(: assuming parseGridRef implements the conversion :)
return some-insertion-function("some-collection-name",
  <entry>
    <name>{$row}</name>
    <latitude>{$coordinates[1]}</latitude>
    <longitude>{$coordinates[2]}</longitude>
  </entry>)
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post. No, I hadn't thought of using an XMl database because the majority of the records will be created from user input within HTMl files. It's only 1 file that I'll add to my database each month. Kind regards.